# Square Brackets With Superscript & Subscript on Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, linear-transformations

Does anybody know what the following notation means?
(I'm referring to the subscript & superscript to the right of the square brackets)

$\psi(T)=[T]_β^γ$

In this case, $T: V \rightarrow W$ is a linear map on finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ & $W$ (over the same field $F$) with dimensions $n$ and $m$ resp. And, $\beta$ & $\gamma$ are ordered bases for resp. $V$ & $W$. Lastly, $\psi$ is the isomorphism $\psi:L(V,W)→M_{m\times n}(F)$.

(Full context here [Proving isomorphism between linear maps and matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201784/proving-isomorphism-between-linear-maps-and-matrices))

Comment: Isn't the OP explaining it at the link:" But this means that $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma} = A$"?

Comment: I suspect it concerns the representation of linear transformations $T$ with respect to a fixed pair of ordered bases.

Comment: If $\beta = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$ and $\gamma = (w_1,\dots,w_m)$, then $[T]_{\beta}^\gamma$ is the $m \times n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}$ such that $T(v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}w_i$ for all $j$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression on the right represents the matrix of the operator $T:V\to W$ with respect to the bases $\beta$ of $V$ and $\gamma$ of $W$.

More specifically, one evaluates T at the $j$-th basis vector in $\beta$ and expresses the output as a linear combination of basis vectors from $\gamma$. The respective coefficients in the linear combination form the $j$-th column of the matrix $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$.